# Animated buttons not show in fire fox browser

Tags: html, css

I have 4 animated buttons on my page in chrome browser it shows fine but in my firefox browser it not show buttons. In my Chrome browser, it works perfectly when I open firefox browser button not show properly.
Following is my code of buttons

My code:

```
<style>
.bttn{
  background: #222 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#222), to(#222), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 150px;
  color: $text-color;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation-name: shine;
  -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
 .bttn{ 

 position: relative;
  width: 128px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
 background-color:#00BCD4 !important;
color: #fff;
}


  .btn_header {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.buttonfx{
  color: black; /* button text color */
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #eee;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  padding: 8px 10px; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 16px 'Bitter', sans-serif; /* use google font */
  line-height: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none; /* remove underline if using A instead of BUTTON tag */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s;
}

/* //// Default effect: Slide from Top  //// */

.buttonfx:before,
.buttonfx:after{

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background:  /* onhover background color */
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3D(0,-100%,0); /* move elements above button so they don't appear initially */
  transition: all .5s;
}

.buttonfx:before{

  background: #00BCD4 !important; /* button default background color */
  z-index: -2;
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
}

.buttonfx:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

.buttonfx:hover:after{
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
  transition: all .5s;
}


.curtainup{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.curtainup:before,
.curtainup:after{
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1,0);
}


.curtainup:hover:before,
.curtainup:hover:after{
  transform: scale(1);
  border-radius: 0;
}


</style>

  <div class="btn_header" id="btn_sticky">
       <div class="close-account row" >  
              <!-- button -->
              <div  class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: ;">
                  <a id=" sampleURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>sample?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; width: 130px;" type="submit" class=" bttn">Request Sample</a>
              </div>
             <!-- /button -->
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: pulse;">
           <a id="discountURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>discount?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; " type="submit" class=" buttonfx curtainup bttn  ">Discount</a>
            </div>

             <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: pulse;">
           <a id="enquiryURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>enquiry?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; "  type="submit" class="buttonfx curtainup bttn ">Enquiry</a>
             </div>

           <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: pulse;">
           <a id="buyURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>buy?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; "  type="submit" class="buttonfx curtainup bttn ">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var btn_header = document.getElementById("btn_sticky");
    var sticky = btn_header.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        btn_header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else {
        btn_header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
</script>
```

following are two images browser 1st chrome browser and 2nd firefox browser
[image: chrome browser]

[image: fire fox browser]

I do not know where I am wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you use `-webkit-` vendor prefix to your animation rules ( and others ). This prefix is specific to `Chrome` and other browsers like Safari but it's not for Firefox. Either use `-moz-` prefix for firefox ( but then it won't work on IE either ) or you should just use non prefixed rules.

Read here about [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

But keep in mind some css properties work only in Chrome.

See here [webkit specific css properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions)

DISCLAIMER : The bellow snippet is not working because you didn't share the `shine` keyframe code and also you seem to use some variables ( maybe less/sass ) which don't work in plain css.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var btn_header = document.getElementById("btn_sticky");
    var sticky = btn_header.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        btn_header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else {
        btn_header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
```

```css
.bttn{
  background: #222 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#222), to(#222), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;
 background-size: 150px;
  color: $text-color;
  background-clip: text;
  animation-name: shine;
  animation-duration: $duration;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
 .bttn{ 

 position: relative;
  width: 128px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
 background-color:#00BCD4 !important;
color: #fff;
}


  .btn_header {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.buttonfx{
  color: black; /* button text color */
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #eee;
  letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
  padding: 8px 10px; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: bold 16px 'Bitter', sans-serif; /* use google font */
  line-height: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none; /* remove underline if using A instead of BUTTON tag */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s;
}

/* //// Default effect: Slide from Top  //// */

.buttonfx:before,
.buttonfx:after{

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background:  /* onhover background color */
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate3D(0,-100%,0); /* move elements above button so they don't appear initially */
  transition: all .5s;
}

.buttonfx:before{

  background: #00BCD4 !important; /* button default background color */
  z-index: -2;
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
}

.buttonfx:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

.buttonfx:hover:after{
  transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
  transition: all .5s;
}


.curtainup{
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.curtainup:before,
.curtainup:after{
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1,0);
}


.curtainup:hover:before,
.curtainup:hover:after{
  transform: scale(1);
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_header" id="btn_sticky">
       <div class="close-account row" >  
              <!-- button -->
              <div  class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: ;">
                  <a id=" sampleURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>sample?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; width: 130px;" type="submit" class=" bttn">Request Sample</a>
              </div>
             <!-- /button -->
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: pulse;">
           <a id="discountURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>discount?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; " type="submit" class=" buttonfx curtainup bttn  ">Discount</a>
            </div>

             <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: pulse;">
           <a id="enquiryURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>enquiry?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; "  type="submit" class="buttonfx curtainup bttn ">Enquiry</a>
             </div>

           <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3  wow pulse animated" data-wow-delay="300 ms" data-wow-iteration="infinite" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 2s; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-name: pulse;">
           <a id="buyURL" href="<?php echo base_url();?>buy?reportId=<?php echo $reportId; ?>" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px; "  type="submit" class="buttonfx curtainup bttn ">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```